# How should core-rim detrital zircon ages be reported in a sedimentary provenance study?

Tags: geology, sedimentology, geochronology

I understand this might be drifting into the black hole of subjectivity but I would like to know if anyone knows if there is a generally accepted practice. If one has a detrital zircon with a core age of 1100 Ma and a rim age of 400 Ma and one wanted to construct one of the many graphs for visualizing such data (e.g. KDE, PDP, histogram plots), would one report both ages or only one? If only one age is to be reported, then does one choose the core or the rim? If you choose the core, then perhaps it reveals something about the ultimate source of the zircon. But the rim would most likely represent the source from which the sediment was derived (this being the goal of a provenance study!). However, if you have other detrital zircons in your sample that yield an age of 1100 Ma then perhaps one can include both the core and rim ages?